# yii smtp mail extension web application error

Tags: php, email, yii, smtp, yii-extensions

In my yii config file I used the following smtp configuration settings:

```
'Smtpmail'=>array(
           'class'=>'application.extensions.smtpmail.PHPMailer',
           'Host'=>"secure.emailsrvr.com",
           'Username'=>'admin@obusiness.com',
           'Password'=>'admin',
           'Mailer'=>'smtp',
           'Port'=>465,
           'SMTPAuth'=>true, 
           'SMTPSecure' => 'tls',
       ),
```

In controller file I used the following code to send the mail

```
$subject = UserModule::t("You have requested the password recovery site {site_name}",
$message = UserModule::t("You have requested the password recovery site {site_name}. To receive a new                            password, go to {activation_url}.",
$user->office_mail;
      $mail=Yii::app()->Smtpmail;
$mail->SetFrom('office@optisol.com', 'From NAme');
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$mail->AddAddress($user->office_mail);
if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else {
echo "Message sent!";
}
```

I use SMTP mail extension to send mail using the above code. I have received the following error message

```
"Property "CWebApplication.Smtpmail" is not defined"
```

I searched about this error in google, but I couldn't find the exact solution. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Under which `key` of the config array have you written the `'Smtpmail'` code? Is it under `components`?

Comment: yse it is in under components

Comment: Not able to find any other reason for such an error. It should only occur when the `Smtpmail` is not under `components` or is misspelled. Do let us know when you find the actual reason.

Comment: We have verified the code and smtp details are under components only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tru this this may help to you

```
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/smtp-mail/
```